# Imaging and the Electric Field

Tags: optics, electric-fields, lenses, imaging

In [this book](https://books.google.ca/books?id=51e0UkEuBP4C&pg=PA162&dq=focussing%20propagating%20waves&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEMQ6AEwCGoVChMIlrGK6ZfvxgIV0CqICh3PZQXc#v=onepage&q=focussing%20propagating%20waves&f=false) (pg. 162), it mentioned that conventional lenses only focus propagating waves, thereby creating an imperfect image. In contrast, superlenses focus both propagating and evanescent waves, where the evanescent waves carry the finer details of the object.

How exactly does focusing the propagating EM waves image an object? I have a rough understanding of imaging from the ray optics point of view, but I'm at a loss when we look at imaging from the point of view of the electric field.

Comment: A ray is the normal vector to the constant phase surface of  the propagating wave. It is a fundamental law (Malus' theorem) of optics and it is effectively equivalent to Fermat's principle (theorem?) that there are orthogonal surfaces to the rays and they stay so after arbitrary number of reflections and/or refraction in a isotropic medium. So the constant phase surfaces of the propagating waves are equally applicable to describe geometrical optics as ray optics can.